# customizing one-fits-all by using rxjs instead of xstream

Tags: cyclejs

This [great template](https://github.com/cyclejs-community/one-fits-all) comes with a set of defaults that I need to customize. One thing I could not resolve is how to replace the xstream library by rxjs. Any example somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace import { run } from '@cycle/run' with import { run } from '@cycle/rxjs-run'. That way the drivers will return observables. But you are right that should be documented